# What percentage of the people on SO program in C# vs. Java?

Tags: discussion, languages

What percentage of the people in SO program in C#?  What percentage program in Java?

Do these percentages change as a function of reputation?  If so, how?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox

Comment: I'm looking forward for the query... :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, since the Java and C# tags are the most active, as you go higher up the rep scale, you will find more and more Java/C# devs because it is easier to earn reputation in busier tags.

Comment: I don't think you are right. My average vote/answer in C++ is much higher than C#. I think it's also true for high rep users like Jon. There are more people that answer Java/C# questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for **questions asked** you could look at the numbers on the tags;

```
c#      28587     1.00 (relative to C#)
.net    17413     0.61
java    15108     0.53
asp.net 13711     0.48
c++     10298     0.36
```

For the site as a **resource** for people with questions (i.e. ***who is going to read your question***)... here's some page stats for per-tag searches that I've munged a little bit - I've scaled to 1 (so everything is relative to C#) since I don't think I should post raw page counts...:

```
c#      1.00
.net    0.56
java    0.54
asp.net 0.41
c++     0.40
```

I can't speak about how this compares to rep without a lot of analsis - but certainly the popular tags are very well represented on SO.